# Python - how do i encode my python script

Tags: python, encryption, encode

I want to encode my script to be unable to see codes
 and **Uneditable**.

and be impossible to decode.

Because it has license...

Thanks.

Comment: The best search term for this is "obfuscation".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

Comment: An even _better_ solution is to have a solid licensing agreement. Fundamentally, this is a legal issue, not a technical one. Looking for a technical solution is misguided at best.

Comment: why use python then? it is an intepreted language. whatever you do to obfuscate it - it just makes it harder, not impossible to decode into something sensible. you could create an executable from it but even then you could disassemle something with enough energy and motivation in it

Answer (score 1):

> I want to encode my script to be unable to see codes

Can't be done.  The script obviously has to be readable for the user's computer to run it.

> and **Uneditable**

Again, impossible.  If the script lives on someone else's computer, they have permission to do anything they want.

The closest thing you can do is to distribute your script as a `.pyc` instead of a `.py` file.  But even then, a knowledgeable user will be able to decode it.

It sounds like you might not want to distribute a script at all, but maintain a back-end API instead.  This way the user never has access to your code in the first place.